# ionic 5 login with google is not working while in android production app

Tags: android, google-signin, ionic5

I am working on ionic5 in my project login with google is working on build apk but same apk file upload on play store. This app downloaded on play store that time login with google is not working.

Please guide me what is the issue in my app.

Thank you.

I am expecting that login with google functionality is working on production apk/app.